# Cómo hago que mi página de Angular tome datos del Back-end en un servidor

Tags: javascript, mysql, angular, ubuntu

Tengo una página en Angular que funciona correctamente desde mi pc, pero necesito subirla a un servidor de Ubuntu. Ya usé el comando ng build y pasé la carpeta dist y back-end al servidor y una vez estando ahí la página no toma los servicios del back-end, usé npm start en el servidor, pero sigue sin poder tomar los datos ni archivos y no sé a qué se deba.

Al usar npm start en la carpeta de back-end del servidor no me da ningún error, pero al accesar a la página se me despliegan múltiples errores de que no se pudo acceder a los datos:

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
[image: Errores en consola]

Este es mi código en config.json:

```js
{
  "development": {
    "username": "pnat001",
    "password": "pass",
    "database": "productos",
    "host": "192.168.0.49",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "pnat001",
    "password": "pass",
    "database": "productos",
    "host": "192.168.0.49",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "pnat001",
    "password": "pass",
    "database": "productos",
    "host": "192.168.0.49",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "token_secret":"tokenPieNat!"
}
```

y esta es la dirección global que estoy utilizando:

```js
export var GLOBAL={
    url:'http://localhost:8010/api/'
}
```

Comment: ¿Seguro que tu server tiene esa ip `"host": "192.168.0.49",` ?

Comment: Sí, es con esa con la que acceso a la página y al servidor en Putty

Comment: ¿y sí puedes realizar peticiones desde postman al server?

Comment: Yo creo que todo tiene que ver con esa  variable que pusiste al final,  porque usas localhost si esta subida a un servidor?, yo creo que algunas cosas las tienes apuntando a localhost y no a tu servidor y a eso se debe tu inconveniente.

Comment: De hecho si, fijate que en la misma imagen de errores que pusiste aparece connection refused para localhost, estas usando entonces en alguna parte la direccion localhost  y no la dirección del servidor.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, lamento no haber respondido a sus comentarios antes, pero encontré la solución a mi problema xd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución, lo que hice fue definir lo siguiente en el archivo environments.ts:

```js
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  url:'http://192.168.0.49:8010/api/'
};
```

y esto lo importé en mis servicios para que usen esa dirección en lugar de localhost.